# "tasse de vin" vs "verre de vin" - difference

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, régionalismes

I'm not a native French speaker but have always ordered "une tasse de [vin] rouge" ('vin' optional) at the bar. My partner (and her living-in-France-but-not-native-speaker parents) say I should be ordering "une verre de [vin] rouge". Does "une tasse de [vin] rouge" make any sense at all? If so, what is the difference "tasse" vs. "verre"? Using "verre" sounds far more formal and more like a reference to the glass itself to me. Is it a regional thing?

Answer (score 9):

This not about formalism. Both *tasse* and *verre* can be used with the same language levels. They just happen to be significantly different containers.

People drink water, wine (and cold beverages) in *verres* (glasses) that have no handle, e.g.:

[image]

and coffee (and hot beverages) in *tasses* (cups) that have a single handle:

[image]

A *tasse de vin* doesn't make sense<sup>1</sup>. Nobody drinks wine in *tasses* at a bar.

One of the only drinks that is generally served in glasses but might be served in a cup (or a bowl with no handle) is the *cidre*, thus *une bolée de cidre*:

[image]

Some *verres* have a handle and are called *chopes*, sometimes used to drink beer.

Some tall *verres* are called *flutes*:

[image]

shallow ones are called *coupes* <sup>2</sup>:

[image]

and spherical ones are called *ballons*.

*Flutes* and *coupes* are mostly used with champagne while *ballons* are used to drink red wine so you might have asked:

> *un ballon de rouge* (informal).

[image]

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that in wineries (*caves*) and among wine professionals, a small metallic cup (often in silver) with a handle was traditionally used to look at and taste wine and called a *tasse à vin* or *tastevin*. Here *taste* is the same word as the English verb *to taste* (modern French *tâter*). The similarity with *tasse* is a pure coincidence. Generally, the wine tasted by professionals (and reasonable *amateurs*) is spit and not drunk, and the trend is to use glasses instead of *tasses à vin*. In any case, it is not expected for a *tasse à vin* to be available at a bar. Credits to @aCOSwt for pointing this rare *tasse à vin*.</sub>

[image]

<sup>2</sup> <sub>I guess your mistake is due to the fact the English "cup" might translate to *tasse* (cup of tea - *tasse de thé*), *coupe* (World Cup - Coupe du monde, Cup of champagne - Coupe de champagne), and *verre* / *[gobelet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobelet_(vaisselle))* like tumblers in a fast-food. "Cup-holders" in cars or planes are called *[porte-gobelets](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porte-gobelet)*. People still often say *coupe de champagne* even while using *flutes* but anyway, *coupes* are not used to drink red wine so none of *tasse*, *coupe* or *gobelet* would have work at a bar.</sub>

Comment: Very good answer. I'll add that I often hear friends saying _tasse_ when talking about a glass of alcohol. Mostly beer. As in _On va boire une tasse ?_.

Comment: Excellent travail de jlliagre!

Comment: @BBBreiz Je viens de rajouter une bolée à ta santé ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre pour la tasse à vin, tu peux aller aux hospices de Beaune, j'y suis allé ce weekend dernier, c'est bien le musée incontournable de Bourgogne ;)